How can I get spark session to run on my Docker container? (It's already configured to run on Jupyter notebook files within the environment)
I am running a a Spark image on Docker container via Python on VSCode.
It's configured to run spark sessions on any jupyter notebook within the environment.
I want to create a spark session on a new python script within the environment, but it doesn't recognize PySpark as a module.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
This is my sample.py file where I'm trying to create a spark session and use dataframes
My devcontainer.json file
My docker-compose.yaml file
My Dockerfile file
As you can see, my jupyter notebook file runs just fine
I tried multiple ways to install packages locally (without using docker, but adding spark to my local environment was tough).
I tried to rebuild my container but that didn't work.
I know I must be missing some kind of configuration in my files, I think.
